# Query in button error on the first click flutter

Tags: flutter

I have problem in button to search user by phone number. When I press button for the first time, query can't retrieve the data, like this : [Debug Console 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDZF.jpg). But if I press button again for the second time or more, query can retrieve the data, like this : [Debug Console 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYtZT.jpg).

This is my button code :

```
Widget tmblKonfirm() {
  return Center(
      child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: () async{
        await pr.show();
        print('NoHP : ' + nohp);
        final dataUser = FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child("users")
          .orderByChild("pengguna_nomor")
          .equalTo(nohp);

        print('Data User : ' + dataUser.toString());

        dataUser.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snapshot.value;
          setState(() {
            testUser = snapshot.value.toString();
          });

          data.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
          });
        });
        print('User 1 : ' + lists.toString());

        pr.hide();

        if (_formKeyKonfirm.currentState.validate()) {
          print('User 2 : ' + testUser.toString());
          if (testUser != 'null'){
            // setState(() {
              sttsUser = true;
            // });
            // showWidgetTopup();          
          }
          else {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(                      
                  content: Text(
                      'Nomor HP tidak terdaftar'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      child: Text('OK'),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }
      },
      child: Text('Konfirmasi',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25)),
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataUser is a Query so you always have to fetch the data snapshot (once() or onValue)

Instead of `dataUser.once().then` use `await dataUser.once()`, otherwise the snapshot callback can be actually called after the onPressed function finishes